# Does Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get() break spock?

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I am working on a legacy grails 2.4.x app.

I wanted to add some extra exception visibility to a class that extends ThreadPoolExecutor

As per 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.Throwable-

I implemented

```
   protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
     super.afterExecute(r, t);
     if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
       try {
         Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
       } catch (CancellationException ce) {
           t = ce;
       } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
           t = ee.getCause();
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
       }
     }
     if (t != null)
       System.out.println(t);
   }
 }
```

However spock seems to stop running when it hits the `Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get()`  line of code

Is this a know issue? 
Something I am doing wrong?

The spock version is: 
version='0.7-groovy-2.0'

Comment: Tests will definitely have issues when u run async code from tests, google around for how to test asynchronouse code with spock

Comment: I don't think Spock really stops running when you hit that.  I expect what is happening is your test is running to completion before the future follows through with its work, which would make sense.  Is that what is happening?

Comment: Feels like a job for `CountDownLatch`

Comment: The Spock version is outdated, Spock 1.1 is the current one. Furthermore, where is your test code? And what do you mean it stops running? `Future.get` is a blocking call so if it does not complete then it will wait there.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings You are correct - it was not completing and waiting.  I have added return behaviour to the `Future.get` (for example )  `future.get() >> { _ ->   throw new CancellationException() }`    re Spock Version -- I am stuck on an old grails 2.4.3. app at the moment;  I don't know how easy this is to upgrade the spock  dependency on